# ArcObjects: Intersect feature class with polygon

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, arcobjects

I have feature class with polylines. I need to intersect the circle polygon.

```
ITopologicalOperator3 topOperator = (ITopologicalOperator3)pPoly;
topOperator.IsKnownSimple_2 = false;
topOperator.Simplify();
IGeometry resultGeom = topOperator.Intersect(polyline2, esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry1Dimension);
```

it gives me result in complete different place.

input output:
[image: input output]

Comment: which of the two geometries is `pPoly` and which is `polyline2`?

Comment: pPoly is circle polygon, polyline2 line.

Comment: And what output do you expect?

Comment: I have a feature class with polylines in it. i need to have the polylines that are inside the polygon that intersects.

Comment: you mean that the result lays at totally different coordinates, away from the original line?